# Ampersand not working inside for loop in shell script

Tags: shell

I need to execute

```
node simulator.js 1 &
node simulator.js 2 &
node simulator.js 3 &
node simulator.js 4 &
node simulator.js 5 &
...
node simulator.js 10 &
```

So, I was trying out the shell script for loop to do this, but I am getting this error.

```
user@host$ for i in {1..10}; do node simulator.js "${i}" &; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I am pretty new to Shell scripts, might be a very small thing here, can someone help figure it out?

**UPDATE**

the issue with not with the for loop, 
its with the `&`, the error persists even if I do

```
for i in {1..10}; do node simulator.js 1 &; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is semi-colon after `&`.

This should work

```
for i in {1..10}; do node simulator.js 1 & done
```

This will fork 10 subshell processes.

Comment: This works great, but when i try to run the loop 1000 times, the terminal hangs at 420, and everything freezes, is there any limit to that? or is it dependent on the hardware?

Comment: I believe `ulimit -u` defines **max user processes**

Comment: Actually my whole system hanged, not sure if that will change with ulimit, but I'll give it a shot. I had to force shut down my system and restart, when I did a 1000 loop. It felt like the processes took a lot of memory perhaps, not sure.

Comment: Yes there is a memory limit also. You may consider GNU parallels for controlled background processing.